# Can't be accessed from outside the local server using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm a newbie to Nginx, on my VPS, there's no problem to get nginx to work locally when I ssh to it,

curl -v localhost or curl -v 127.0.0.1

but it can't be accessed outside the VPS

curl -v 58.215.176.164 or curl -v markson.hk

here is my conf file

```
user  www-data www-data;
worker_processes  2;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.markson.hk;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
     root   /usr/local/src/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }



        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
```

**update-----------------**

all the web services outside the local server are not working, I tried sinatra, riak.

same thing, can't access outside the local server

I took some advice from the first person who answered my question, the ufw is not active, and i can ssh to the vps, which means the port 22 is open,  so I don't think it's due to the firewall.

I think the problem dues to ip forwarding or some sort?

Anyone can give me some clue or provide some reading materials about the ip forwarding and linux network configuration?

Comment: solved,the problem is the VPS provider set their own security method which I had known before which is grandclould.cn promise to be the Amazon cloud service provider in China, any Chinese Programmer should check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your firewall open to allow traffic on port 80 incoming?

Comment: Don't know how to check that, the It's Ubuntu hardy that installed on my VPS